# Show that system of linear equations A$\textbf{x}$ = $\textbf{b}$ has a solution over $\mathbb{N}$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let's say we have a system of linear equations A$\textbf{x}$ =  $\textbf{b}$ with all coefficients in $\mathbb{N}$ as follows:

$$
\begin{align}
a_{1,1}x_{1} + \cdots + a_{1,L}x_L & = b_1 \\
& {}\,\vdots \\
a_{m,1}x_{1} + \cdots + a_{m,L}x_L & = b_m
\end{align}
$$

$L$ is a very large number and $m$ is a smaller number. Furthermore, let $I$ be the subset of indices ${\{1,\ldots,L\}}$ and $A_{I}$ the result of keeping only columns indexed by $I$.

Suppose that $u = (u_1,\ldots,u_L)$ is a solution of A$\textbf{x} = \textbf{b}$. Let $K= \{l \mid 1 \leq l \leq L, u_l > 0\}$, and let $k = |K|$. Thus, $K$ is the set of indices for which $u$ has a non-zero entry, and k is the number of non-zero entries in $u$. Suppose in addition that $k$ is minimal: there are no solutions with fewer than $k$ non-zero entries.

If we let $I$ and $J$ be subsets of K, how can it be shown that, if $I \ne \emptyset$, but $I \cap J = \emptyset$,  then the vectors $A_I u_I$ and $A_J u_J$ must be different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**. $x + x = 0 + 2x$, thus $x + x$ cannot be a minimal solution. Note that $Au$ depends linearly on $A_Iu_I$ and $A_Ju_J$.